# Shell script wait till process completes

Tags: shell, process

I have a process

```
"verifyEmail"
I run this in script as verifyEmail 0 1000
```

Now How do I wait until this process is finished executing before moving on to next instruction in shell script ? It takes more than 60 mins for verifyEmail to run

I tried

```
while ! checkprocess "verifyEmail"; do   ##Checkprocess is a function which returns 0 or 1
sleep 60                                 ## based on process present or not
done
```

Comment: More than 60 minutes to run? that's some intense verification. `sleep 60` only sleeps for 60 *seconds*. Also, why is it not running synchronously? are you backgrounding it or something?

Answer (score 2):

If you run the process normally, you don't need to do anything.  If you run it asynchronously, you just need to `wait` for it:

```
verifyEmail 0 1000
echo This will print after verifyEmail is done!
```

or

```
verifyEmail 0 1000 &
wait $!
echo This will print after verifyEmail is done!
```

Comment: Sorry, but both of them does not work. I scripted and ran the script, later checked with ps -ef command and still verifyEmail was running in background

Comment: Your verifyEmail script is daemonizing itself.  It probably provides a mechanism to disable that, or to write a pidfile.